# How can I store an indefinite amount of stuff in a field of my database table?

Tags: database, database-design

Heres a simple version of the website I'm designing: Users can belong to one or more groups. As many groups as they want. When they log in they are presented with the groups the belong to. Ideally, in my Users table I'd like an array or something that is unbounded to which I can keep on adding the IDs of the groups that user joins.

Additionally, although I realize this isn't necessary, I might want a column in my Group table which has an indefinite amount of user IDs which belong in that group. (side question: would that be more efficient than getting all the users of the group by querying the user table for users belonging to a certain group ID?)

Does my question make sense? Mainly I want to be able to fill a column up with an indefinite list of IDs... The only way I can think of is making it like some super long varchar and having the list JSON encoded in there or something, but ewww
Please and thanks

Oh and its a mysql database (my website is in php), but 2 years of php development I've recently decided php sucks and I hate it and ASP .NET web applications is the only way for me so I guess I'll be implementing this on whatever kind of database I'll need for that.

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, it sounds like it could be paraphrased this way:  which is better, repeating groups or first normal form?

Comment: What is first normal form?

Comment: First Normal Form is the first in a whole series of normal forms that were discovered in the course of developing the relational model.  It was the first one discovered, but it's called first because it's the least restrictive.  If you learn data normalization, you will learn several normal forms.  You will also learn ways of producing a design that might be better than many other designs.

Comment: Good video on database normalization and the first 3 normal forms: http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/database-fundamentals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct; you don't want to have one column of unbounded length just to hold the user's groups. Instead, create a table such as `user_group_membership` with the columns:

- `user_id`
- `group_id`

A single `user_id` could have multiple rows, each with the same `user_id` but a different `group_id`. You would represent membership in multiple groups by adding multiple rows to this table.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a [many-to-many](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) relationship. A "many-to-many" relationship is represented by a third, joining table that contains both primary keys of the related entities. You might also hear this called a *bridge table*, a *junction table*, or an *associative entity*.

You have the following relationships:

- A `User` belongs to many `Groups`
- A `Group` can have many `Users`

In database design, this might be represented as follows:

[image]

This way, a `UserGroup` represents any combination of a `User` and a `Group` without the problem of having "infinite columns."

Answer (score 1):

If you store an indefinite amount of data in one field, your design does not conform to [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).  FNF is the first step in a design pattern called data normalization.  Data normalization is a major aspect of database design.  Normalized design is usually good design although there are some situations where a different design pattern might be better adapted.

If your data is not in FNF, you will end up doing sequential scans for some queries where a normalized database would be accessed via a quick lookup.  For a table with a billion rows, this could mean delaying an hour rather than a few seconds.  FNF guarantees a direct access lookup path for each item of data.

As other responders have indicated, such a design will involve more than one table, to be joined at retrieval time.  Joining takes some time, but it's tiny compared to the time wasted in sequential scans, if the data volume is large.